# Open window and move to next line of code don't wait to close the window

Tags: vb.net

In my VB.Net code, below code is used to open the window and following we have multiple checks. Currently the checks are executed when close the window but the current requirement to open the window independently and continue to flow no need to wait till close the window.

```
oFrm.ShowDialog(Me)
```

trying async process but unable to achieve.

Comment: use oFrm.Show() ?

Comment: ShowDialog blocks because if makes the form modal.  Show does not.

Comment: It's in the documentation: [code following it is not executed until after the dialog box is closed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8). If you don't want to block, I'll have to use Show(). If your checks are on the new form, that code could be moved to oFrm

Answer (score 2):

From the remarks in [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netframework-4.8):

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
>   application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
>   executed until after the dialog box is closed.

Versus [Show()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.show?view=netframework-4.8):

> You can use this method to display a non-modal form.

The keywords here are **modal** and **non-modal**.

See [Modal window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window) for some explanations about the differences.